# :not selector is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There should be a `mouseup` event for entire body contents except one element and its child. I had written the following code to achieve it,

```
$('body > *:not(.element_to_be_excluded)').mouseup(...);
```

This works good in Firefox. The mouseup event is not fired when i click inside `.element_to_be_excluded`. But in IE `mouseup` event is fired everywhere inside body. It is not excluding `.element_to_be_excluded`. Is there anything wrong or is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: what version of IE you are using?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, It's IE Edge

Comment: Could be something to do with your selector being a CSS one. Have you try instead: `$('body').children().not('.element_to_be_excluded').mouseup(...);`?  But if so, i have no idea why. Maybe this has something to do with the fact you are using invalid HTML markup instead. Anyway, you have to post MCVE

Comment: You should check caniuse.com. According to http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot, Edge has no support in Edge 13, unknown at 14 (for selectors); it is only supported in css. So I'm afraid you will just have to wait until it is supported !